# d3.js, applying transitions to data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, force-layout

So I'm using d3 with a force layout and want to move a fixed node over time. Using a transition() would make sense here, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply a transition to the node's bound data, rather than attributes of the svg object. Is this possible, or should I just write a simple setTimeout() with an interpolation?

Comment: In the end, only attributes of the svg object will result in a visible animation. Can you elaborate a bit about why you think transitioning data is what you want?

Comment: While I could attr('transform', 'translate()') the visible SVG object, the node would still "be" at it's old location, affecting the simulation (ie, repelling other nodes, the target for links, etc). For the simulation to work right, the node's x/y coordinates need to match with the visible SVG object. So, to smoothly move a fixed node (which is no longer having its data object's x/y attributes updated by the force layout), I'd like to use a transition. I guess I could transition the visible SVG object and just set the data object x/y immediately, but that feels sort of wrong

Answer (score 0):

here is the [tutorial](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions)

or you can try

```
window.setTimeout(someFunction, 2000);
```

in function you can get nodes of your graph and change the xy in that and just update it.

another [example](https://gist.github.com/ZoltanLajosKis/1095727)

if you need example then feel free for it